# Different print behaviour between linux and macOS

Tags: c, linux, macos, printing

I'm trying to print out a table containing some elements in the console. I've got a macbook pro, partitioned with linux mint. In linux this works perfectly, everything prints correctly.

In macOs however I do not get expected results. I will link the source code at the bottom.
The source is written in linux but I'm just using standard C stuff.

Here is what I get.

[MacOS Terminal:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vts6ivwwsqb0bg/macOS.jpg?m)

[Linux Terminal:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adj7tnl9f03hkg7/linux.jpg?m)

I'm very new to using linux and compiling between two different operating systems. Is there anything I'm overlooking here.

[the source: Ctables.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkv1yh926wwymav/Ctables.h?m)

### source code

```
/**************************************************************
*
*   Ctables.h
*
*
**/
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
 
#define MAX_OPS 3
 
 
enum {
    FREELY = 2,
    STRICT,
    COLORFUL,
    RAINBOW,
    CENTER,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    NONE
};
 
typedef enum{FALSE,TRUE}bool;
 
typedef struct {
    char *str;
    char *color;
    int width;
    int cell_width;
    int max_cell_w;
}table_cell;
 
 
typedef struct {
    int row_dimension;
    int col_dimension;
    int index_i;
    int index_j;
    int options[MAX_OPS];
    table_cell **info;
    int capacity;
 
}table_t;
/*Extra functions*/
void ms(int space, char symbol); /*prints space or a given symbol*/
int return_biggest(table_t *table, int row); /*finds the biggest string in a given row*/
int *calculate_width(table_t *table);
 
/*Operations*/
table_t *initialze_table(int op[], int dim_i , int dim_j);
void add(table_t *table, char *str);
void print(table_t *table);
void free_table(table_t *table);
 
 
/*initialize a table, what kind it is
 
    Op: fill in the array with your options, pass it to the struct
 
    0. STRICT - User adds dimensions, table handles the indexing
       FREELY - Data is added to table and user
            handles indexing
    1. Options - COLORFUL : make table sensitive to color and higlighting
             RAINBOW : print table in rainbow colors, this will
                automatically turn on colors as well
    2. Alignment - CENTER, LEFT, RIGHT
 
    example:
        int options[3] = {STRICT, COLORFUL, CENTER};
    --create new table
        table_t neu_tableu = initialize_table(options,5,5);
            makes a colorful new table of size 5 * 5
         
 
         
*/
void ms(int space, char symbol) {
int i;
 
    if(symbol == 's') {
 
    for(i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        printf(" ");
        }
    }
 
    else {
     
    for(i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        printf("%c",symbol);
        }
         
    }
 
}
 
int return_biggest(table_t *table, int row) {
int i;
int biggest = table -> info[0][row].width;
    for(i = 0; i < table -> row_dimension; i++) {
        if(table -> info[i][row].width > biggest) {
            biggest = table -> info[i][row].width;
        }
    }
 
    return biggest;
 
}
 
int *calculate_width(table_t *table) {
int i,j;
/*Nr of elements to calculate*/  
int elements = table -> col_dimension;
    /*make container*/
    int *array_biggest = (int *)malloc(elements * sizeof(int));
     
    /*Fill container with biggest element in each row*/
        for(i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
            array_biggest[i] = return_biggest(table,i);
        }
 
/*
    LEFT: Has no space at the beginning, 4 columns at the end
        |example    |
    RIGHT:
          4 columns at the beginning
        |    example|
    CENTER:
        2 columns at beginning, 2 at the end
        |  example  |
 
Note: this is compared to the longest string, to make everything fit
    we have to calculate each space needed for each smaller string
    added to the table in terms of formatting specs
 
*/
    if(table -> options[2] > 6)  {
        for(i = 0; i < table -> col_dimension;i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < table -> row_dimension; j++) {
            if(table -> info[j][i].width < array_biggest[i]) {
                table -> info[j][i].cell_width = ((array_biggest[i] + 4) - table -> info[j][i].width);
            }
            else {
                table -> info[j][i].cell_width = 4;
            }
            table -> info[j][i].max_cell_w = array_biggest[i] + 4;
            }
        }
        }
    else {
        for(i = 0; i < table -> col_dimension; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < table -> row_dimension; j++) {
                if(table -> info[j][i].width < array_biggest[i]) {
                    table -> info[j][i].cell_width = ((array_biggest[i] + 4) - table -> info[j][i].width) / 2;
    }
                else {
                    table -> info[j][i].cell_width = 2;
                }
              table -> info[j][i].max_cell_w = array_biggest[i] + 4;
            }
        }
        }
 
        return array_biggest;
}
 
table_t *initialize_table(int op[], int dim_i,int dim_j) {
int i,j;
int mul = dim_i * dim_j;
    table_t *new_table = (table_t *)malloc(sizeof(table_t));        
        new_table -> info = (table_cell **)malloc(sizeof(table_cell *) * dim_i);
    for(i = 0; i < dim_i; i++) {
        new_table -> info[i] = (table_cell *)malloc(sizeof(table_cell) * dim_j);
    }
        new_table -> capacity = dim_i * dim_j;
        new_table -> row_dimension = dim_i;
        new_table -> col_dimension = dim_j;
        new_table -> index_i = 0;
        new_table -> index_j = 0;
 
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_OPS;j++) {
        new_table -> options[j] = op[j];
    }
 
    /*Set default for every cell in the table*/
    for(i = 0; i < new_table -> row_dimension; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < new_table -> col_dimension; j++) {
            new_table -> info[i][j].str = "";    
            new_table -> info[i][j].color = "None";  
            new_table -> info[i][j].width = 0;
            new_table -> info[i][j].cell_width = 4;
        }
    }
 
 
 
    return new_table;
}
 
 
void add(table_t *table, char *in_str) {
 
    table -> info[table -> index_i][table -> index_j].str = in_str;
    table -> info[table -> index_i][table -> index_j].width = strlen(in_str);
 
    table -> index_j++;
        if(table -> index_j == table -> col_dimension) {
            table -> index_j = 0;
            table -> index_i++;
        }   
}
 
void print(table_t *table) {
int i,j;
int *width_arr = calculate_width(table);
int wide = 0;
int check_size;
    /*Get overall table width, add together biggest
      strings from all rows*/
    for(i = 0; i < table -> col_dimension; i++) { 
        wide += width_arr[i] + 4;
    }
    /*On top of this, add */
        wide += table -> col_dimension - 1;
 
    printf("+");
    ms(wide,'-');
    printf("+\n");
 
 
    for(i = 0; i < table -> row_dimension; i++) {
        printf("|");
        for(j = 0; j < table -> col_dimension; j++) {
        switch(table -> options[2]) {
        case LEFT:
            printf("%s",table -> info[i][j].str);
            ms(table -> info[i][j].cell_width,'s');
            printf("|");
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            ms(table -> info[i][j].cell_width,'s');
            printf("%s", table -> info[i][j].str);
            printf("|");
            break;
        case CENTER:
        check_size = (table -> info[i][j].cell_width + table -> info[i][j].width + table ->info[i][j].cell_width);
        if(check_size < table -> info[i][j].max_cell_w) 
         {
            ms(table -> info[i][j].cell_width,'s');
            printf("%s", table -> info[i][j].str);
            ms(table -> info[i][j].cell_width + table -> info[i][j].max_cell_w - check_size,'s');
        }
        else {
            ms(table -> info[i][j].cell_width,'s');
            printf("%s", table -> info[i][j].str);
            ms(table -> info[i][j].cell_width,'s');
        }
            printf("|");
            break;
     
        }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    printf("+");
    ms(wide,'-');
    printf("+");
 
        printf("\n");
 
    /*FREE CONTAINER*/
        free(width_arr);
 
}
 
void free_table(table_t *table) {
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < table -> row_dimension; i++) {
        free(table ->info[i]);
    }
    free(table -> info);
        free(table);
 
}
```

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Please use it to step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: Oh, and you should learn how to compile and link together two source files, because implementation should really not be placed in header files.

Comment: Please always paste your code into the question so that it is still available if you remove it from your dropbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the var wide lines 220 is not init :(

please init it to zero or whatever

```
int wide; //<------- DECLARATION
int check_size;
    /*Get overall table width, add together biggest
      strings from all rows*/
    for(i = 0; i < table -> col_dimension; i++) { 
        wide += width_arr[i] + 4; //<----------- USE
    }
    /*On top of this, add */
        wide += table -> col_dimension - 2; //<----------- USE

    printf("+");
    ms(wide,'-'); //<----------- USE
    printf("+\n");
```

You have declaration but not initialisation

You are just lucky on linux because wide equals 0 but not in Mac OS

Comment: Wow thank you, I'll be more careful with my initialisations from now on!